# Не импортируется django

Tags: python, windows, django, импорт

Ошибка:

```
File "manage.py", line 17, in <module>
    "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available
on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate
a virtual environment?
```

Я скачал джанго с помощью `pip install Django` до этого я скачал виртуал , а если попробовать написать `django --version` то выйдет: *"django" не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом*.

Comment: Вы задали 7 вопросов за сутки. Не стать вам программистом, если не будете пытаться разобраться самостоятельно.

Comment: хех,целый день пытаюсь любыми способами это сделать.А так с вами полностью согласен,наверное это потому что сегодня я только 1 раз использивал этот сайт.

Comment: Что подразумеваете под "виртуал"? virtualenv?

Comment: @Taras, судя по всему "пальцем в небо" один из вариантов: 1. Django установлен на системный python, а досту пытаетесь получить из под виртуального окружения. 2. с точностью наоборот. Нужно просто проверить куда установился пакет и под каким python пытаетесь получить доступ к пакету.

Comment: Привет, я вообще не сильно разбираюсь что ты сказал , так как я новичок.Но я знаю что у меня django установился в c:\users\x\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packagesP.S Виртуал тоесть virtualenv

Comment: покажите результат команд: `py -c "import django; print(django.get_version())"` и `py -m pip install django`  В сам вопрос вывод в консоль этих команд, как есть добавьте, можно использовать кнопку [edit]

Comment: +jfs результат команды py -m pip install django равен Requirement already satisfied: django in c:\users\x\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages.А если написать py -c "import django; print(django.get_version())"  то покажет 1.11.5.P.S версия моего патойна 3.6

Comment: не публикуйте информацию необходимую для ответа в комментариях. Отредактируйте ваш вопрос вместо этого. (попробуйте на ссылку в моём предыдущем комментарии нажать)

Comment: Окей,больше не буду,так ты знаешь что делать?Я уже не могу,с этим вопросом задолбался